# Displaying an multiple excel tables into different tabs (one table per tab)

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a widget with multiple tabs that are occupied with different excel tables per tab and can't figure why I cant populate each tab separately.

About the tables the number of columns remain the same for all Excel tables only the number of rows change.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore , QtWidgets ,QtGui
import pandas as pd
import os


class MyApp(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.sizeHint().width(), self.sizeHint().height()
        self.resize(self.width(), self.height())

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()

        self.table.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.table.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.table.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.table.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.selected)

        # self.add_flight_tab()
        layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        tab_list = self.add_flight_tab(path_xl)

        for tables , names in zip(range(tab_list.__sizeof__()), tab_list):
            self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(tables)
            self.load_data(f"{path_xl}/{names}")
            self.setLayout(layout)



    def load_data(self, path_to_xl):

        df = pd.read_excel(path_to_xl,sheet_name=0, usecols=["AWB", "Destn.", "SCC", "Agent Name",
                                                              "Stated Pcs/Wgt/Vol (kg/CBM)","Booked Flight"])
        if df.size == 0:
            return

        df.fillna('', inplace=True)

        self.table.setRowCount(df.shape[0])
        self.table.setColumnCount(df.shape[1])
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(df.columns)
        self.table.insertColumn(self.table.columnCount())
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6 , QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Offload"))
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        for row in df.iterrows():
            values = row[1]

            for i in range(df.shape[0]):
                check_box = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                check_box.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                check_box.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.CheckState())
                self.table.setItem(i, 6, check_box)

            for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
                if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
                    value = '{0:0,.0f}'.format(value)
                tableItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                self.table.setItem(row[0], col_index, tableItem)


    def add_flight_tab(self, path_files):
        files = os.listdir(path_files)
        new_ls = []

        for xl, tab_ind in zip(files, range(files.__sizeof__())):
            if xl.endswith(".xlsx") or xl.endswith(".XLSX"):
                new_ls.append(xl)
                self.tabs.insertTab(tab_ind,QtWidgets.QTableWidget(), xl)
                self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(tab_ind)
        return new_ls


if __name__ == '__main__':

   
    path_xl = "path to excel"

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myApp = MyApp()
    myApp.show()
    # print(myApp.add_flight_tab())
    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except SystemExit:
        print("Closing window...")
```

Everything I have tried gives two results(there must be something I'm missing out in here) :

1. [image: Tabs that are not populated]
2. The Widget is populated but the are no other tabs only thing changed is the following lines:

```
layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        tab_list = self.add_flight_tab(path_xl)

        for tables , names in zip(range(tab_list.__sizeof__()), tab_list):
            self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(tables)
            self.load_data(f"{path_xl}/{names}")
            layout.addChildWidget(self.table)
```

For now the names of the tabs is irrelevant , I only need to have number of tabs according to number of Excel files and each tab is filled with table accordingly.

Comment: You have multiple excel tables and only one `QTableWidget` `self.table`, which is not even added to any layout. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out to me. I'll make some changes and hopefully it will work. So if I understood you correctly I need a `QTableWidget` instance per tab I have and then add in the main layout , then there is no need in the `self.table` in the `def __init__(self)` , correct me if I'm wrong. Should I make a method to add the tables?

Comment: Yes, you don't need self.table, you need QTableWidget per tab, and now I see you already have that `self.tabs.insertTab(tab_ind,QtWidgets.QTableWidget())`, you only need to add index parameter to `load_data` function and access specific QTableWidget using `self.tabs.widget(index)`.

Comment: Thank you friend you have helped me a lot. I did what you have suggested and also in the `load_data`  I have returned `table` data therefore needed to change `self.tabs.insertTab(tab_ind,self.load_data(f"{path_xl}/{xl}", tab_ind))` and it worked!!!